# Fine control over SQL Sort Order

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008

I have a SQL Report driven by a query that sorts it in ascending order of some numerical value. But the user wants two particular rows of data, which happen to appear at different ordinal positions in the query results, to be juxtaposed. Is there a way to do this, either through the report's driving SQL or the .rdl file itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add another calculated expression as the first order by Expression, which puts those two values ahead of all others...

```
Select [Other stuff]
From Table
Order By Case colName 
          When first_val then 0
          When second_val then 0
          else 1 End,
      colName
```

or, EDIT (to include @astander's suggestion)

```
Select [Other stuff]
From Table
Order By Case 
         When colName In (first_Val, second_Val)
         Then 0 else 1 End,
      colName
```

and another Edit, to put second_val immediately after first_Val...

```
Select [Other stuff]
From Table
Order By Case 
         When colName < first_Val And colName <> secondVal Then 0
         When colName = first_Val Then 1
         When colName = secondVal Then 2 
         Else 3 End,
      colName
```

Comment: You can shorten that by using **CASE WHEN colName IN(first_val, second_val) then 0**

Comment: I didn't know you could use CASE in the context of ORDER BY.

Comment: @Jonathan,  Sure, you can use Case just about anywhere.

@astander, good one.. I wasn't sure you could use In (List) syntax inside a Case...

Comment: Actually, the problem here is that it places the rows where colName is first_val or second_val atop all other rows, which is not correct. I want, as soon as first_val is discovered, for second_val's row to appear right beneath it.

Comment: @Jonathan, then you need an expression which represents this.  It sounds like all rows are sorted by colName except the one with value = second_val, which needs to be sorted immediately after the row(s) with first_val. so see my edit..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking for this:

`select * from table where col1 = first_val or col1 = second_val;`

where first_val and second_val are the values for the rows that the user wants returned.

If that's not what you're looking for, please clarify your question.

Answer (score -1):

Also, CURSORs are a good tool for fine-grained control. I'm using that, but I will see if it can be stripped of iterative code by using the ORDER BY CASE suggestion.